# Add a TabLayout to a CoordinatorLayout below an anchored Toolbar

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to add a TabLayout to this nice project: https://github.com/saulmm/CoordinatorBehaviorExample

I succeeded to make it look right when the layout is not collapsed but when the layout is collapsed, the TabLayout initially goes under the Toolbar and finally it shows in foreground, and overlaps the Toolbar.

What I want instead is having the TabLayout below the toolbar (something like this https://github.com/vitovalov/TabbedCoordinatorLayout) when the layout is collapsed.

Here is my modified main layout:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded"
    >

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/main.appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        >

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/main.collapsing"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed|snap"
            >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/main.imageview.placeholder"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="300dp"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/quila2"
                android:tint="#11000000"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="0.9"
                />

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/main.framelayout.title"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
                android:background="@color/primary"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="0.3"
                >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/main.linearlayout.title"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    >

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:gravity="bottom|center"
                        android:text="@string/quila_name"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                        android:textSize="30sp"
                        />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                        android:text="@string/quila_tagline"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                        />

                </LinearLayout>
            </FrameLayout>
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="Today"/>
            <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="Last Month"/>
            <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="Overall"/>
        </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        app:behavior_overlapTop="0dp"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"

        >

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            app:cardElevation="8dp"
            app:contentPadding="16dp"
            >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:lineSpacingExtra="8dp"
                android:text="@string/lorem"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                />
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/main.toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/primary"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/main.framelayout.title"
        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
        app:title=""
        >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            >

            <Space
                android:layout_width="@dimen/image_final_width"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/image_final_width"
                />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/main.textview.title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:text="@string/quila_name2"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                />

        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        android:layout_width="@dimen/image_width"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/image_width"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:src="@drawable/quila"
        app:border_color="@android:color/white"
        app:border_width="2dp"
        app:finalHeight="@dimen/image_final_width"
        app:finalYPosition="2dp"
        app:layout_behavior="saulmm.myapplication.AvatarImageBehavior"
        app:startHeight="2dp"
        app:startToolbarPosition="2dp"
        app:startXPosition="2dp"
        />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```